# What's difference between npm web3 version1 and version4?

Tags: web3js, npm

```
async function sendDonate() {
try {
  const result = await contract.methods.donate().send({
    from: account,
    value: web3.utils.toWei(inputValue, "ether"),
  });
  console.log(result); 
  return result; 
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
  throw error; 
}
```

}

I'm prcticing to make donation contract with React + web3.
when I installed npm i web3 latest version(4.x.x) There is error.
But I installed npm i web3 version(1.x.x), it's working.

What's differences?

In version4, must use typescript?

Comment: What's the error? They are just not compatible. It alwasy takes some time until most packages migrate to a new release. There's an upgrade guide in the official site: https://docs.web3js.org/guides/web3_upgrade_guide/x/.